# How to use BeautifulSoup to get real-time stock price on website?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, element

I am working on a project to get the real-time stock price on http://www.jpmhkwarrants.com/en_hk/market-statistics/underlying/underlying-terms/code/1. I have searched online and tried several way to get the price, but still fail. Here is my code:

```
def getStockPrice():
      url = "http://www.jpmhkwarrants.com/zh_hk/market-statistics/underlying/underlying-terms/code/1" 
       r = urlopen(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), 'lxmll)
      price = soup.find(id = "real_time_box").find({"span", "class":"price"})
      print(price)
```

The output is "None". I know that the price is scripted in the function above but I have no idea how to get the price. Can it be solved by beautifulsoup or else module?

Comment: Website is loading data dynamically. you should use `selenium`(easiest), `request-html` or `Scrapy` to run JavaScript, then you can gain the full data.

Comment: why you need to parse those website if you can get the OHLC price from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0001.hk?ltr=1 using available python library?

Comment: @RosdyanaKusuma I have no idea yahoo finance has provided a python library. I will check it out now. Thanks for your remind

Comment: @RosdyanaKusuma I pulled the project from github and ran the test.py which just gave me a bunch of error. Besides, does yahoo-finance provide the europe and hong kong stock info.? Seems it only provide the US's stock info.

Comment: @WILLIAM, I used to do a research about stock market prediction in Taiwan, Hongkong, UK and Indonesia for my publication, this is the code to download the ohlc price https://gist.github.com/rosdyana/e8f2c74efe9ead876300aa258007bb8a .

Comment: @RosdyanaKusuma Thank you so much for your sharing. It does inspire me a  lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view the page source you will see html like this

```
<div class="table detail">
    .....
    <div class="tl">即市走勢 <span class="description">前收市價</span>
    .....
    <td>買入價(延遲*)<span>82.15</span></td>
```

the `span` that we want is in index 2, select it with

```
price = soup.select('.table.detail td span')[1]
print(price.text)
```

Demo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="python">
 <code data-type="sample-code">
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from urllib.request import urlopen

  def getStockPrice():
        url = "http://www.jpmhkwarrants.com/zh_hk/market-statistics/underlying/underlying-terms/code/1" 
        r = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), 'html.parser')
        price = soup.select('.table.detail td span')[1]
        print(price.text)

  getStockPrice()
 </code>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It shows the index error: list index out of range. I guess it is not possible to get the price by beautifulsoup since which is in a javascript.

Comment: strange, I tried on multiple machine it return expected result, can you try to run code snippet above?

Comment: Thank so much. It works after I change 'lxml' to 'html.parser' as your demo code. Would you mind to explain a bit more about why it can directly parse the price but need not to run and get the price from the javascript function? Thank you again.

Comment: the data available from `html` and `javascript` and it taken from `html` which is static text.

Comment: I have a question again. Why I can't the the same way to get the data in div id="real_time_box"?

Comment: because it generated by javascript, you need `selenium` to get that.